# Remote connection cannot find file on Computer 2 when remoting from Computer 1 to Computer 2

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm writing a PowerShell script that remote connects from Computer 1 (C1) to Computer 2 (C2) using Enter-PSSession and then accesses files from C2 to use those files for an executable that I call using Invoke-Expression. My problem is that the files I want to access aren't being found, so the script fails.

This is what my script looks like:

```bsh
Enter-PSSession -Computername C2 -Credential $mycreds -Authentication Credssp
$executablePath = "C:\...\executable.exe"
$file1 = "C:\file\i\want\to\access\" # both files stored on C2
$file2 = "C:\other\file\i\want\"
$arguments = "Syntax to call files"
Invoke-Expression "$executablePath $arguments"
```

and this is the error message I get:

```bsh
File "C:\file\i\want\to\access\" not found .
File "C:\other\file\i\want\" not found .
```

I tried putting `Start-Sleep -Seconds 30` after the `Enter-PSSession...` command, but that didn't fix anything and the files still couldn't be found.
I put a `write-host $env:COMPUTERNAME` call into the script between connecting to C2 and calling `Invoke-Expression`, and it returns C1. However, after the script fails, `$env:COMPUTERNAME` returns C2, and I can tell from the console output that it's connected to C2. It seems to me that PowerShell is processing the entire script at once, and so all the commands are in the scope of C1 and not C2. Then, afterwards, it points to C2. Is it possible to stagger the commands such that I can ensure the `Invoke-Expression` command is going through C2?

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` only works interactively - in a script you need to use `Invoke-Command`

Comment: Both `$file` and `$file2` have a REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) at the end. This typically represents a directory and not a file item.

Comment: what @MathiasR.Jessen said. You can't script enter-pssession. when using `invoke-command` make sure to add the option `-sessionoption (new-pssessionoption -nomachineprofile)` otherwise youll create a profile on every machine you remote to. slows down your process and is bad practice.

Comment: Also, because it apparently can't be said enough, [DO NOT use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen/Robert Cotterman, thanks! I didn't realize Enter-PSSession was interactive, I'm now using New-PSSession and it works!

Comment: @lit thanks, I didn't realize I actually had those backslashes tacked on the end of the file.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers, interesting read, but they don't really offer alternatives to using Invoke-Expression. What would you recommend I replace Invoke-Expression with?

Comment: if any of you want to make your comment an answer so that I can mark it as correct that'd be cool :)

Comment: The call operator (`&`) or `Start-Process`, depending on the situation.